# Jenkins and gitlab sharing build slaves

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

Let's say you have a gitlab instance and it already uses Jenkins for all its CI builds via the gitlab Jenkins plugin, etc. The Jenkins setup has a modest collection of build slaves providing a variety of platforms, etc. and each slave is set up to run just one job at a time (i.e. a Jenkins job gets exclusive access to the build slave, which is important for reasons I won't go into here).

Now let's say you want to consider using gitlab's own native CI support, moving one or more projects over to gitlab instead of Jenkins. The gitlab CI would need to use the same set of build slaves, but it needs to play nice with Jenkins and the two need to cooperate so that if one runs a job on a particular slave, the other won't submit a job to that same slave until the first finishes. In effect, while Jenkins is running a job on a slave, gitlab should see that slave as unavailable and vice versa.

Anyone have working methods for getting gitlab to tell Jenkins it is using a slave while it runs a CI job on there and vice versa? The method doesn't have to be 100% bullet proof, it would potentially be okay if both gitlab and Jenkins run a job on the same slave at the same time if it is a rare event (i.e. race conditions could potentially be tolerated if the frequency of occurrence is likely to be low).

**Additional info**:

- Build slaves include Linux, Windows and Apple.
- Docker is not used and would not be permitted at this time.
- We have full admin access to everything, but changing code in gitlab or Jenkins themselves would be rejected. Adding scripts or plugins would be okay.